# Nivo Slider lists up the images instead of sliding

Tags: 7, javascript

I download this module with `drush dl nivo_slider`
Then enable and automatically download libraries with `drush en nivo_slider`
Then clean cache with: `drush cc all`
Then enable in block.

Then Firebug said: `TypeError: $(...).nivoSlider is not a function
$('#slider').nivoSlider({`

and chromium said: 
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function nivo_slider.js?ne2hej:11Drupal.behaviors.nivoSlider.attach nivo_slider.js?ne2hej:11(anonymous function) drupal.js?ne2hej:76b.extend.each jquery.min.js?v=1.9.1:3Drupal.attachBehaviors drupal.js?ne2hej:74(anonymous function) drupal.js?ne2hej:412c jquery.min.js?v=1.9.1:3p.fireWith jquery.min.js?v=1.9.1:3b.extend.ready jquery.min.js?v=1.9.1:3H jquery.min.js?v=1.9.1:3`

I'm using later version of Drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an installation priority issue with [Nivo Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/nivo_slider) module and [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module or Nivo Slider library files.

Since you installed all required modules and placed [Nivo Slider](https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider) library files in the right location as explained in the installation steps:

> To install Nivo Slider:
>
> 1. Download the latest version of the Nivo Slider jQuery plugin and
>      extract it to *sites/all/libraries* or *sites/sitename/libraries* as you
>      require.
> 2. The extracted folder must be named nivo-slider. Enable Nivo
>      Slider and all of the modules that it requires.
> 3. Configure the jQuery
>      Update module to use jQuery 1.7 or higher.

Now you need to disable [Nivo Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/nivo_slider) module by running this command `drush pm-disable nivo_slider`, then you need to uninstall [Nivo Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/nivo_slider) module by running this command `drush pm-uninstall nivo_slider`, then install [Nivo Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/nivo_slider) again by running this command `drush en nivo_slider`.

Don't forget to clear Drupal cache after you finish uninstalling and installing the module; just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I've done this but I still have the problem. Even reinstall drupal! and do `drush dl nivo_slider` change jquery to version 1.7 and assign block and `drush en nivo_slider`, Do else should I do?

Comment: @Daniyal reinstalling Drupal wont help you. Check if you any status errors at `admin/reports/status` and make sure you have installed Libraries API module first and placed Nivo Slider jquery files in the place then install Nivo Slider Drupal plugin. Make sure to set jQuery to 1.9 or higher. Also check if your Drupal is loading this file `sites/all/libraries/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js`